# How to display iPhone contacts like path

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How to display iPhone contacts with email like path application.

I tried following code, its show the contacts name, when I click the contact it navigate to contact details page. But, I need to display contacts in table view then user click customer row the dialog box is open it contain contacts email like path application.

```
var values = {cancel:function(){}};
values.fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phone', 'email'];

values.selectedProperty = function(e) {
    if(e.property == 'email')
    {
        alert(e.person.email);
    }
 };
$.contactWin.addEventListener('open', function(e){
   Titanium.Contacts.showContacts(values);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link. It will show you how you can get contacts from contacts then you can create a table with custom row as you want.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts